# get data from two tables with the help of joins or by another way?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, activerecord

I want to get data form two tables, one is "User" and other is "Packages" like "bronze, silver, gold". How to show that user who has a bronze package?

User Table:

```
Userid email    pass amount
 1     a@d.com  123  200
 2     b@d.com  123  100
 3     c@d.com  123  300
 4     d@d.com  123  500
```

Packages:

```
packId userid package
  1       1    gold
  2       2    bronze
  3       3    bronze
  4       4    bronze
```

Show Result like this:

```
d@d.com 123 500 bronze
c@d.com 123 300 bronze
b@d.com 123 100 bronze
```

My function:

```
public function getUserBronze(){
        $this->db->select('amount'); 
        $this->db->from('user u');
        $this->db->join('package up', 'u.account=up.userid', 'INNER');
        $this->db->order_by('amount',"DESC");
        $this->db->where('amount!=', 0);
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
       }
```

Comment: this helps a lot to understand joins: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join on userid and select where package is equal to 'bronze'

```
public function getUserBvList(){
    $this->db->select('u.*, up.package') 
         ->from('user u')
         ->join('user_package up', 'u.Userid=up.userid')
         ->where('package', 'bronze');
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
   }
```

Comment: thanks... not exact but i got idea from your code. again thanks because i have solved my problem.